# How should I refactor this nested IF statement?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have this function which has more then 3 nested if statement(4 nested If in the function). I am trying to solve sonar issue where it says to `refactor this code to not nest more than 3 IF/FOR/WHILE/TRY statements`. I searched around but couldn't find anything too useful is it possible to reduce? - if so, how would I go about doing so? Any feedback are appreciated

Here is the function

```
function find(animals) {

    var animalsCode = getByanimals(animals);

    if (typeof animalsCode !== 'undefined' && !isanimalsSupported(animalsCode)) ---> Nesting 1{

        var url = $('.menu-select-animals li[data-animals="' + animalsCode + '"] a').attr('href');
        var newQuery = '';

        if (url) {    ---->Nesting 2
            var redirectQuery = '';
            if (window.location.search) {

            //some logic
            }
            if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {    ---->Nesting 3

               //some logic

                if (typeof join[1] !== 'undefined') { ---->Nesting 4

             //some code
                }
            }

            if (typeof mergedQueries !== 'undefined');
            }
        } else {
          //some code
        }
     else {
        handleanimals();
    }
}
    return {
    handleanimals();
    },

    windows: function() {
      if (typeof theSrc !== 'undefined') {
      // some logic
      }

      if (typeof animalsCheckTheSrc !== 'undefined') {

        if (animalsCookie !== animalsCheckTheSrc) {
        // some logic
        }
        checkanimalsCookie(animalsCheckTheSrc);
      } }}};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you fix your code sample please? It looks like it's missing at least one closing brace.

Comment: Edited my code.

Comment: If you have a working code and is looking for a review, you might want to check https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: This code is not for review, trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to reason about your function because it doesn't return anything. I would have a very hard time tracing the flow of a program that relied on these side-effect only functions like this.

But, one thing you could probably do is decompose this function more and start using return values. For instance, split off this piece of code, and return the redirectURL in your new function.

```
if (redirectURL) {    ---->Nesting 2

            var pageQuery = '';

            var redirectQuery = '';
            if (window.location.search) {

                pageQuery = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

            }
            if (redirectURL.indexOf('?') > -1) {    ---->Nesting 3

                var redirectSplit = redirectURL.split('?');

                redirectURL = redirectSplit[0];


                if (typeof redirectSplit[1] !== 'undefined') { ---->Nesting 4

                    redirectQuery = redirectSplit[1].split('&');

                }
            }
            var mergedQueries = com.trp.fai.utility.mergeStringArrays(redirectQuery, pageQuery);



            if (typeof mergedQueries !== 'undefined' && mergedQueries.length > 0) {

                newQuery = '?' + mergedQueries.join('&');

            }
        } else {

            redirectURL = 'http://corporate.troweprice.com';

            newQuery = '?src=' + countryCode;

        }
```

If you need to return multiple items you can either use global variables or return an object and destructure it on the other side.

Comment: Thanks for quick solution, it does return but in other function, add some more details to code if you can please check

Comment: Hey this did not work for me, could you please suggest some solution, thanks

Comment: @Karan you're not providing much context, can you edit your OP to clarify what errors you're seeing now?

Comment: I do not see any error, I have added more details to my code, if you can have a look once

Comment: @Karan is that sonarqube error gone? Have you tried tracing your code using breakpoints in DevTools to see if a variable holds an unexpected value at some point?

Comment: Still figuring out, what do you suggest? If possible can you map out the solution?